# Compound Protocol: Which contract holds the collateral?

Tags: solidity, dapps, defi

I would like to recreate compound.finance as a project but I don't really understand the architecture. Their white paper of website wasn't really helpful in this matter.

When I want to borrow I first have to add tokens that can be used as a collateral.

Then I can borrow but which contract stores the collateral? Is it the Comptroller or cToken contract?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cToken is the address that is holding the underlying asset, u can check that by checking lets say DAI, DaiContractAddr.balanceOf(cToken)

Here is where user transfer their collateral to cToken address

https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/CErc20.sol#L156